Cannot import 'rpool': I/0 error. Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source
Some days ago I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 and after several reboots with no problems I now have a complete black screen on startup. If I go into recovery mode I get the following error:

Failed to import pool 'rpool'. Manually import the pool and exit.

Read several answers to the above error and tried:
zpool import -f rpool

Which throws:

cannot import 'rpool': I/0 error. Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source.

I'm not sure this is necessary beacuse with zpool import rpool state appears "ONLINE" with the following messages:

Some supported feature are not enabled on the pool.

&

some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.

Edit:
With a Live USB I ran Disks utility and when trying to mount rpool i get:

Error mounting /dev/nvme0n1p4 at /media/ubuntu/rpool: unknown filseystem type 'zfs_member' (udisk-error-quark,0)

How do I proceed now?

Tried several zpool and zfs command combinations with no successes so I reinstalled the system choosing now LVM instead of ZFZ. I think it's more appropriate for my single laptop use. Luckily I had a not too-distant backup.
